# Change citation language temporarily

Tags: biblatex, xetex, polyglossia, german

I use XeLaTex with Biblatex to write my thesis, which is in English. When I cite two authors I get "X and Y", which is fine. However, I have one part of the thesis which is a German abstract, and in that part only I would like to get "X und Y". How do I do that?

Comment: Did you set the language to german?

Comment: Yes, the entire abstract is in a \begin{german} environment.

Comment: Can you show us a mminimal example? Setting up a document trying to reproduce what you see just takes too long.

Comment: Normally `biblatex` adapts the language to its surroundings. In `\documentclass[ngerman,british]{article}        
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}

\begin{otherlanguage}{ngerman}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\end{otherlanguage}

\cite{sigfridsson}
\end{document}`. I get "and" in the first and third citation and "und" in the second.

Comment: See also [`biblatex` issue #359](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/359)

Comment: PLK has committed a fix for the issue that as far as I can tell fixes the issue. The update is not yet on CTAN, but can be found in the [development folder at sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex/files/development/). I'm sure your feedback would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The [issue (#359)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/359) has already been addressed by the `biblatex` developers (in [commit 0513325](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/051332544030462b7e030287e38fbc105d7e14b4)).
An updated version has not yet made it to CTAN, but can be found in the [development folder at sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex/files/development/).

The following lines now reproduce the official fix

```
\makeatletter
\protected\def\blx@citeinit{%
  \iftoggle{blx@bibliography}
    {}
    {\toggletrue{blx@citation}}%
  \blx@blxinit
  \blx@langstrings
  \citesetup
  \blx@setsfcodes
  \blx@postpunct@agroup
  \blx@resetdata
  \blx@leavevmode
  \csuse{blx@hook@cite}%
  \csuse{blx@hook@cite@next}%
  \let\blx@citeinit\blx@resetdata}
\makeatother
```

and can be put into your preamble to get the desired behaviour for the time being.

I leave my original answer below for reference

---

`biblatex`'s `polyglossia` interface is still in the preliminary stages and some of the elaborate trickery done with `babel` cannot be mapped one-to-one to `polyglossia`, one thing is that `polyglossia` needs a nudge to load `biblatex`'s localisation. `biblatex` already has a command to ensure this, but it is not applied when switching languages via `polyglossia`'s commands.

You can use

```
\makeatletter
\apptocmd\select@@language{\blx@langstrings}
\makeatother
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}        
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguage{german}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\apptocmd\select@@language{\blx@langstrings}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}

\begin{german}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\end{german}

\cite{sigfridsson}
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: Thanks! I try to use this hack but I get the following error: `! File ended while scanning use of \@firstoftwo.`

Comment: @Ariel It does work in my example on my machine. Did you try the exact example? If so did it work? Can you show a short example how it doesn't work for you, please?

Comment: @Ariel You can also reproduce the official fix as shown above, maybe you want to try that as well.

Comment: @moewe Very helpful. Is that multilanguage support in the meantime integrated? Or do I still need to use the above hack?

Comment: @EtoAls Yes, the fix mentioned at the beginning of the answer was released in `biblatex` v3.2 (2015-12-28). But `polyglossia` support was significantly improved in `biblatex` v3.14 (2019-12-01). If you want to use `polyglossia` and `biblatex`, make sure your system is fully up to date. In any case, the workarounds from this answer have not been necessary for a long time.